# SQL COUNT with condition and without - using JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, join

My goal is something like following table:

```
Key      | Count since date X | Count total
1        | 4                  | 28
```

With two simple selects I could gain this values: (the key of the table consists of 3 columns `[t$ncmp, t$trav, t$seqn]`)

```
1. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  db.table WHERE t$date >= sysdate-2 GROUP BY t$ncmp, t$trav, t$seqn
2. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  db.table GROUP BY t$ncmp, t$trav, t$seqn
```

How can I join these statements?

What I tried:

```
SELECT n.t$trav, COUNT(n.t$trav), m.total FROM db.table n 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t$ncmp, t$trav, t$seqn, COUNT(*) as total FROM db.table
           GROUP BY t$ncmp, t$trav, t$seqn) m 
ON (n.t$ncmp = m.t$ncmp AND n.t$trav = m.t$trav AND n.t$seqn = m.t$seqn)
WHERE n.t$date >= sysdate-2
GROUP BY n.t$ncmp, n.t$trav, n.t$seqn
```

I tried different variantes, but always got errors like 'group by is missing' or 'unknown qualifier'.
Now this at least executes, but total is always 2.

```
T$TRAV  COUNT(N.T$TRAV) TOTAL
4       2                   2
29      3                   2
51      1                   2
62      2                   2
16      1                   2
....
```

If it matter, I will run this as an OPENQUERY from MSSQLSERVER to Oracle-DB.

Comment: I'd try `GROUP BY n.t$trav, m.total`. You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, _except those who are arguments to set functions_.

Comment: @jarlh omg yes, that's it! thank you! Sometimes it's the obvious things :D you may post this as an answer, I'd accept it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try

```
GROUP BY n.t$trav, m.total
```

You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT` - except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 1):

> My goal is something like following table:

If so, you seem to want conditional aggregation:

```
select key, count(*) as total,
       sum(case when datecol >= date 'xxxx-xx-xx' then 1 else 0 end) as total_since_x
from t
group by key;
```

I'm not sure how this relates to your sample queries.  I simply don't see the relationship between that code and your question.

Comment: that's cool, I used it to get rid of the JOIN clause. :D (but used JOIN anyway to build a statement more complex...) :D